# Use fast deployment uncheckable (debug only mode) Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I can't check the fast deployment (debug only mode) on Xamarin. I don't know why. What could I do? I need to run in debug mode.

[image]

Comment: What is your version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31112.23 (sorry for the delay, I was on my vacations)

Comment: Any idea? What is it the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution: be sure the option "enable developer instruction" is marked

[image]